# Heroku review apps broken - source blob is not a valid tarball

Tags: heroku

Review app creation in my heroku pipeline are broken. I get the error, 'source blob is not a valid tarball'. I don't get any logs, hence can't investigate into or fix anything myself.

Any ideas on a fix, or how to dig deeper?

Comment: I've had the same issue, so this may be a wider issue with Heroku?

Comment: Here is what heroku support mentioned: >This is only affecting a handful of customers, so I suspect it has something to do with the size of your source archive. I will provide more details when we have more to report.

Comment: There was nothing to do on our end. Heroku eventually fixed the problem on their end!